# django-tables2: how to pass other object instance to the template besides the one we use for the table

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I created a table using django-tables2 and everything is working fince except that I want to add other instances or variable to the url template.

Here is my view:

```
def SpecificPLayer(request, playerslug):

    player = Player_Bios.objects.get(player_id=playerslug)
    table= StatTable(BatStat.objects.filter(player_id=playerslug).values('season','team_id'))
    RequestConfig(request, paginate=False).configure(table)

    return render(request, 'singleplayer.html', {'table': table})
```

What about if I want to pass the following to the template:

```
today = date.today()
```

My common sense told me to do this:

```
 return render(request, 'singleplayer.html','today':taday {'table': table}) #does not work
```

on my singleplayer.html, I have the following:

```
  {{ today }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is:

```
 return render(request, 'singleplayer.html', {'table': table, 'today':taday})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have all of the variable that you want to use in the view inside the dictionary.